# How to type text in input element in Selenium without finding the input element?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a python script that uses Selenium and, in the script, a Google Login (OAuth) button is clicked and a new window is displayed as shown below:

[image: New window screenshot]

In the new window, thanks to the superb UX :P, the input element for the email field is already selected. Since the field is already selected, can I use Selenium to just start typing **without** finding the input element and using `send_key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch to active element [`.switch_to.active_element`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) :

```
element = driver.switch_to.active_element
element.send_keys('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('hotmail.com')
actions.perform()
```

Try using action chains to send the keys over.